# MongoDB: not all the results are returned from a query, using $geoNear

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got this query :

```
 exports.search = (req, res) => {

  let lat1 = req.body.lat;
  let lon1 = req.body.lng;
  let page = req.body.page || 1;
  let perPage = req.body.perPage || 10;
  let radius = req.body.radius || 100000; // This is not causing the issue, i can remove it and the issue is still here


  var options = { page: page, limit: perPage, sortBy: { updatedDate: -1 } }

  let match = {}

  var aggregate = null;

  if (lat1 && lon1) {

    aggregate = Tutor.aggregate([
      {
        "$geoNear": {
          "near": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [lon1, lat1]
          },
          "distanceField": "distance", // this calculated distance will be compared in next section
          "distanceMultiplier": 0.001,
          "spherical": true,
          "key": "loc",
          "maxDistance": radius
        }
      },
      {
        $match: match
      },
      { "$addFields": { "islt": { "$cond": [{ "$lt": ["$distance", "$range"] }, true, false] } } },
      { "$match": { "islt": true } },
      { "$project": { "islt": 0 } }
    ])
    // .allowDiskUse(true);
  } else {
    aggregate = Tutor.aggregate([
      {
        $match: match
      }
    ]);
  }



  Tutor
    .aggregatePaginate(aggregate, options, function (err, result, pageCount, count) {

      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(400).send(err);
      }
      else {

        var opts = [
          { path: 'levels', select: 'name' },
          { path: 'subjects', select: 'name' },
          { path: 'assos', select: 'name' }
        ];
        Tutor
          .populate(result, opts)
          .then(result2 => {
            return res.send({
              page: page,
              perPage: perPage,
              pageCount: pageCount,
              documentCount: count,
              tutors: result2
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            return res.status(400).send(err);
          });
      }
    })
};
```

The query is supposed to retrieve all the tutors in a given range (which is a field from the tutor model, an integer in km, indicating how far the tutor is willing to move) around a certain location. (lat1, lon1).

The issue is that all the documents are not returned. After many tests, I have noticed that only tutors that are less than approximatively 7.5km away from the location are returned and not the others. Even if the tutor is 10km away and has a range of 15km, he won't be returned as he is farer than 7.5km.

I have tried switching location between two tutors (one that is returned and one that is not but should be) to see if this is the only thing causing the issue and it is. After I switched their location (lng and loc), the one that was returned before is no longer and vice versa.

I really don't get why this is happening.

Also, I know the result size is less than 16MB since I don't get all the results, even with allowDiskUse:true.

**If you have any other idea about why I'm not getting all the results, don't hesitate !**

Thank you !

PS : this is a part of the tutor model with the concerned fields (loc):

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import validate from 'mongoose-validator';
import { User } from './user';
import mongooseAggregatePaginate from 'mongoose-aggregate-paginate';

var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;


var rangeValidator = [
    validate({
        validator: (v) => {
            v.isInteger && v >= 0 && v <= 100;
        },
        message: '{VALUE} is a wrong value for range'
    })
];



var tutorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [1, 'Full name can not be empty'],
        required: [true, 'Full name is required']
    },
    location: {
        address_components: [
            {
                long_name: String,
                short_name: String,
                types: String
            }
        ],
        description: String,
        lat: Number,
        lng: Number

    },
    loc: {
        type: { type: String },
        coordinates: []
    },


});

tutorSchema.plugin(mongooseAggregatePaginate);
tutorSchema.index({ "loc": "2dsphere" });
var Tutor = User.discriminator('Tutor', tutorSchema);


module.exports = {
    Tutor
};
```

The user model is using two indexes. The ID and this one ;

```
db['system.indexes'].find() Raw Output
{
  "v": 2,
  "key": {
    "loc": "2dsphere"
  },
  "name": "loc_2dsphere",
  "background": true,
  "2dsphereIndexVersion": 3,
  "ns": "verygoodprof.users"
}
```

Comment: To check whether it is problem of 16 MB you can use `allowDiskUse :true` it will use your hard disk as storage. With this option if you get all result then it is problem of  `16MB`. Otherwise something wrong with query.

Comment: Ok thanks !  where do I write this "allowDiskUse:true" ?

Comment: Refer this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#aggregate-data-using-external-sort

Comment: Unfortunately it is not because of the 16MB ... :(

Comment: It is working with `allowDiskUse:true` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Then its a issue of query

Comment: isn't your probably simply that you put the radius as the maxdistance value ?
because the Maxdistance value is normally described in meters.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is the same if I remove the maxDistance field

Comment: Is the query working well when you run it on the shell directly ? Is the problem specifically with the distance multiplier and max distance fields ? What is your mongoose and mongo server version ?

Comment: I did not try on the shell directly. "mongodb" (as db.version returns): "3.4.10",
"mongoose": "5.3.4"

Comment: The problem is definitely not related to the maxDistance field as there is the same issue with or without this field. It may be related to the distance multiplier but I really don't think so

Comment: I would make sure the index is built correctly. If feasible drop the collection, add the documents and add the index and try query again. Also try in shell and include `mongoose.set('debug', true)`  to inspect the queries that are sent over to mongo. Good luck!

Comment: How do I make sure the index is built correctly ? Dropping the collection is not really possible :s

Comment: By "dropping the collection", do you mean dropping the indexes of the collection ? Is this doable without breaking the db ? I have added the indexes I am using in the question above so you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have some similar kind of problem, in my case there is problem with limit

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

by default limit is 100 (Optional. The maximum number of documents to return. The default value is 100).

If you want you can increase the limit. Hope it help

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I only have like 20 documents returned (should be 30-40, aproximatively)

Comment: You were right !!! This was the issue :o Geonear was returning more than 100 documents but as I had other filters after, only like 30 were actually returned. So I thought this was not the issue. But it was ! So stupid oh my god so many hours wasted ... Thanks !

Comment: No problem I also not think that in your case other filter effect the result of $geonear it can help some others ....

Answer (score 1):

You are using `spherical: true`, having the semantics different from planar geospacial queries.

Also, since you are using a GeoJSON object, instead of plain coordinates, the distance MUST be provided in meters (or in kilometers, since you are using the .001 multiplier)

When using `spherical: true`, it uses the `$nearSphere` query: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/#op._S_nearSphere

With `spherical: false`, mongo uses the `$near` query: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near

Since you are working with Lat/Lng, meaning planar coordinates, you should disable the spherical option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, disabling the spherical option is not allowed :

errmsg: 'geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "2dsphere index must have spherical: true", code: 17301, codeName: "Location17301" }',

Comment: If that is the case, then we have an inconsistency here. You are building your query on top of mongo 4 documentation, but your server is 3.x...

Comment: Yes the server is 3.4.10. So I guess one solution would be to upgrade the server version ? Can't I avoid it ? Isn't there another way to do what I want with the current version ?

Comment: Not really, but my guess is that the problem does not lie with the $geoNear, but with the other aggregation steps. Could you please try removing the last 3 steps and replace them with `{ "$match": { "$lt": [ "$distance", "$range" ] } }` ?

Answer (score 0):

The distance returned by [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) in case of `"spherical": true` is in radians so you need to change the `"distanceMultiplier": 6371` to be equal to earth radius  to get the distance in Km.

Comment: Maybe do I have to modify the field "range" of the tutor which is expressed in km ?

Comment: I see what you mean as the docs say so but unfortunately there is still something wrong since when I put 6371, only the documents at distance = 0 are returned

Comment: I tried with 6,371 also (6371 x 0.001) as the range field is expressed in km and the distance is computed in meters but still the same issue ...

Comment: The maxdistance should be in meters,  the distance multiplier is for the results returned so this should be 6371 if you want distancefield to be in Kms, but it has no relation with the filtering of data

Comment: I am not talking about the maxDistance but about the distance computed between the results and the query point. This distance is rightly computed in meters (not in radians) when I don't put any distanceMultiplier. (I have checked). It is expressed in Km when I put 0.001. But putting 6371 does not compute the right distance. I don't think this is the issue. Thank you for your try though :)